# Scheduled-triggered flow debugging doesn't obey Rollback mode setting

Tags: visual-workflow

**Given**:

- A scheduled-triggered flow associated to no objects.
- With a single element to call an invocable Apex action that does DML

[image]

**When**:

- I debug the Flow (`Debug` button), the flow executes, the Apex method is called, the database is updated (per the Apex class' debug log)
- The DML is rolled back

EVEN IF THE `Run Flow in rollback mode` IS LEFT UNCHECKED ⚠️

The above is true regardless of activation state of the flow.

I can't find any doc on this behavior -- seems counterintiutive