# Email Alert from Scheduled Flow is Not sending

Tags: apex, workflow, scheduled-apex

I have the following scheduled flow that calls all accounts and send an email alert. For some reason, none of the email alerts are being sent from the scheduled flow.

[image]

We have been checking our spam folder
and for noreply@salesforce.com emails, and nothing has surfaced.

Below is a screen shot of the current settings for the email alert. Curious to understand what is going on here.

[image]

Further more, we analyze the debug details and all the data seems to be flowing properly.

[image]

Comment: does it work once activated or are you testing solely within Flow debug -- if latter, see [related question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/327660/scheduled-triggered-flow-debugging-doesnt-obey-rollback-mode-setting) (mine) which suggests that debugging scheduled flows always runs in rollback mode - hence no emails sent

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I solved it - I set an automated process user email address. Below is an image to provide additional context.

[image]